# I have two types of users - User and Admin. I would like to include a session check, to check if the person is logging on as a user or as an admin.

Tags: php, session, admin

This is the code I've included :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) OR $_SESSION['userid']==''){

   header('Location: Loginhome.php');

}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type'] =='Admin'){
     header('Location: adminhome.php');

}
else{
     header('Location: userhome.php');
   exit;
}

?>
```

And this code says that the page isn't redirecting properly after logging in.

Comment: Please add content of userhome.php here.

Comment: Store type of user in database and at the time of login set `$_SESSION['user_type']` and there you go.

Comment: Do you have this bit included in adminhome.php as well? If so, I have an inkling what the redirection problem might be. But if not, how are you handling people going to adminhome.php by typing its url without logging in first?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['user_type']=='1']) OR $_SESSION['userid']==''){

    header('Location: Loginhome.php');

  }
 else
if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']=='2']) && $_SESSION['user_type'] =='Admin'){
     header('Location: adminhome.php');

 }
 else{
   header('Location: userhome.php');
   exit;
   }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this things

you need to helpful this one

declare a role

//for admin

if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 1) {

//your code here

}

//for user all

if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 2 && $_SESSION['user']['name'] == $username) {

//your code here

}

good luck guys

Comment: @hardik_kothiya Please proper format your code to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['role'] !== 'admin') {
  header('Location: ../index');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Is there any good reason to use `$_SESSION['role']` in your code while the OP used `$_SESSION['user_type']`?

Answer (score -1):

<?php
require_once('config.php'); 
require_once('classes/admin.class.php');
require_once('classes/log.class.php');
$OBJ_LOGIN = new ADMIN();
$OBJ_LOG = new LOG();
//print_r($_SESSION);
if($OBJ_LOGIN->LoggedUser())
{
       redirect('dashboard.php');
}
//$res_login = array();
$flg=0;
$action = $_GET['a'];
if($action == 'logout')
{
//    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO log VALUES(NULL,'".$_SESSION['userempname']."','Log out of the System',NOW())";
    $OBJ_LOG->userName = $_SESSION['userfullname'];
    $OBJ_LOG->logText = 'Log out of the System';
    $res_log = $OBJ_LOG->Addlog();
//    mysql_query($sql1);
    
    if(session_destroy())
    {
       redirect('index.php');
    }
}
if($_POST['logfrm'] == 'yes')
{
    $OBJ_LOGIN->aUsername = $_POST['uname'];
    $OBJ_LOGIN->aPassword = md5($_POST['upwd']);
    $res_login = $OBJ_LOGIN->LoginUser();
    //print_r($res_login);
    
    if($_POST['uname'] == $res_login[0]['aUsername'] && md5($_POST['upwd']) == $res_login[0]['aPassword'])
    {
        $_SESSION['adminid'] = $res_login[0]['adminID'];
        $_SESSION['userrole'] = $res_login[0]['aType'];
        $_SESSION['useremail'] = $res_login[0]['aEmail'];
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $res_login[0]['aUsername'];
        $_SESSION['userpass'] = $res_login[0]['aPassword'];
        $_SESSION['userfullname'] = $res_login[0]['aFullname'];
        $_SESSION['userimg'] = $res_login[0]['aImage'];
        
        $OBJ_LOG->userName = $_SESSION['userfullname'];
        $OBJ_LOG->logText = 'Login into the System';
         $log = $OBJ_LOG->Addlog();
       redirect('dashboard.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $flg = 1;
    }     
}
?>